# Ruby 2.7.0 in termux - FFI:NotFoundError

Tags: ruby, ffi, rbenv, termux, lineageos

My question is regarding using Ruby 2.7.0 (built via rbenv) on termux:-

I'm seeing:-

`FFI::NotFoundError: Function 'getdtablesize' not found in [libc.so]` when I try and run `rake`, I've searched online but haven't managed to find much about this error so far.

Stack trace:-

````
FFI::NotFoundError: Function 'getdtablesize' not found in [libc.so]
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/Projects/myapp/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.11.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:273:in `attach_function'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/Projects/myapp/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:16:in `<module:Libc>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/Projects/myapp/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:6:in `<module:Ethon>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/Projects/myapp/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon/libc.rb:1:in `<main>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/Projects/myapp/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/Projects/myapp/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/Projects/myapp/.bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'```
````

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `getdtablesize` function (which is used by the ethon gem) was removed from the libc of more recent Android distributions, apparently after being [deprecated](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib-getdtablesize.html) for some time.

Thus, to use the ethon gem on your Android distribution, you would need to either:

- adapt the gem to not use the `getdtablesize` function anymore, or
- use a different libc for your project which still provides the function, e.g. the [libc of the GNU project](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/getdtablesize.html)

Comment: Correct, I also arrived there! I patched it and submitted a PR to the gem - https://github.com/tevio/ethon/commit/f0b4aab081f218c51d0501e7e12fb2a177e16300